# How to enable Secure Boot in a guest VM using VMWare Workstation?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, secure-boot

For testing purposes I need to install Windows 10 with the "[Secure boot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824987.aspx)" feature enabled. I do not have any hardware that supports it. Thus I was hoping to emulate it in a virtual machine.

Is there a way to do it in VMWare Workstation 10?

Answer (score 2):

VMWare Workstation 10 supports EFI but not UEFI and Secure Boot.

> Secure boot requires firmware that supports UEFI v2.3.1 Errata B and has the Microsoft Windows Certification Authority in the UEFI signature database.
>
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications

So, I am afraid you cannot.

---

However, you can add Secure Boot via Hyper-V, on generation 2 virtual machines. See:

- Sosnowski, Rafal (29 March 2016). ["Secure Boot on Virtual Machines"](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dubaisec/2016/03/29/secure-boot-on-virtual-machines/). *Dubai Security Blog*. Microsoft.

This version of Hyper-V is included with 64-bit SKUs of Windows 8.1 (Pro or Enterprise) and later, as well as Windows Server 2012 and later. But it is not installed by default. To install it:

1. Press <kbd>⊞ Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> keys
2. Choose "Programs and features" (On Windows 10 1703, you need to choose "Apps and features", then click on "Programs and Features" hyperlink.
3. Click on the "Turn Windows features on or off" hyperlink on the left pane.
4. Turn on Hyper-V. Make sure "Hyper-V > Hyper-V Platform" is turned on. Finally, click OK.

VMware vSphere also supports Secure Boot. Unfortunately, that's not something you can just install on a machine like you install Angry Birds.